# CreateReplica returning nothing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am trying to run a simple createReplica on my feature service in arcpy or outside. Once it's complete I get a message showing the output location, however the output is blank and/or does not provide an output (i.e. FC in gdb or zipfile) like what is done by invoking 
 `https://services.arcgis.com/myservicelayer/ArcGIS/rest/services/service_1eb/FeatureServer/createReplica`

Any idea's on how I can result something substantial? Overall goal is to retrieve attachments from AGOL feature service layer and drop into fgdb in my local directory. I would like to keep this a simple as possible, so pls no suggestions for python API, arcrest or restapi as I am new to python.

```
env.workspace = "S:/General-Offices-GO-02/CAD/GIS/Projects/AGOL2"

# Set local variables
in_data = "https://services1.arcgis.com/something/arcgis/rest/services/myservice/FeatureServer/createReplica"
replica_type = "ONE_WAY_REPLICA"
output_workspace = "C:/Temp/mygdb.gdb"
replica_name = "myRepName1"
access_type = "FULL"
initial_sender = "PARENT_DATA_SENDER"
expand = "USE_DEFAULTS"
reuse_schema = "DO_NOT_REUSE"
get_related = "GET_RELATED"
replica_geometry = "Form_1"
archiving = "DO_NOT_USE_ARCHIVING"

# Execute CreateReplica
arcpy.CreateReplica_management(in_data, replica_type, output_workspace, replica_name, access_type, initial_sender, expand, reuse_schema, get_related, replica_geometry, archiving)
```

Comment: I'm not an expert with this tool, but my best guess: a feature service workspace is not a valid input type. Only a true enterprise geodatabase. The create replica workflow on a FS involves the api on the FS itself: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/create-replica.htm

Comment: Based on your overall goal, I'd give this a read: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012232

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I need to do this with python to later be added to a task scheduler. I have seen almost every piece of info on the net related to this. But I need to learn python, so I can keep going on this stuff, Cheers!

Comment: Ok, so if you need to use Python, you're going to need to figure out HTTP requests or perhaps the Python API. There is no built in arcpy tool that'll do what you want. This script looks to use the Python API to do what you want: https://github.com/Esri/developer-support/tree/master/python/general-python/download-attachments

Comment: @KHibma if I go to the URL with /createReplica at the end + the token I can open the dialog box (REST endpoint) to create a replica that returns a zipfile in my downloads (which is perfect) BUT needs to be done programmatically, if you know what I mean, I will dig into requests as I need to steer clear of Python API for now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out here is the code:

```
import urllib, urllib2, json, time, os

    #variables
    username = "username"                                            
    password = "password"                                            
    replicaURL = "https://services.arcgis.com/eM846565663/arcgis/rest/services/<myservicelayer>/FeatureServer/createReplica"
    replicaLayers = [0]                                              
    replicaName = "myReplica"


    def sendRequest(request):
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        readResponse = response.read()
        jsonResponse = json.loads(readResponse)
        return jsonResponse

    print("Generating token now...")

    url = "https://arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken"
    data = {'username': username,
            'password': password,
            'referer': "https://www.arcgis.com",
            'f': 'json'}
    request = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(data))
    jsonResponse = sendRequest(request)
    token = jsonResponse['token']


    ###Creating the Replica
    print("Creating the replica")
    data = {'f' : 'json',
        'replicaName' : replicaName,
        'layers' : replicaLayers,
        'returnAttachments' : 'true',
        'returnAttachmentsDatabyURL' : 'false',
        'syncModel' : 'none',
        'dataFormat' : 'filegdb',
        'async' : 'true',
        'token': token}
    #request = urllib2.Request(replicaURL, urllib.urlencode(data))
    #jsonResponse = sendRequest(request)
    #print(jsonResponse)
```

Comment: Looks good to me!